# Why am i getting "direct://" as output for my program?

Tags: c, network-programming

I am in the early stages of writing a proxy server in c for class and while debugging, my program gives me a weird output simpley with two lines of

direct://

direct://

what does this mean? I've never had this happen before. The program even outputs this when i dont provide 3 arguments which i required for this program to execute.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

   if(argc!=3){
      printf("Usage: proxy <IP address> <port no.>");
      exit(1);
   }

   int csock, ssock, clen, slen;
   int csocka, ssocka;
   int rc, fd, ttl;
   char method[40];
   char uri[80];
   char prot[40];
   char cbuf[100];
   time_t logtime;
   char * pch;

   struct sockaddr_in caddr;
   struct sockaddr_in caddr2;
   struct sockaddr_in saddr;
   struct sockaddr_in saddr2;

   csock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   caddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   caddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
   caddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
   clen = sizeof(caddr);
   rc = bind(csock, (struct sockaddr *) &caddr, clen);
   if(rc < 0){
      printf("bind failed");
      exit(1);
   }
   rc = listen(csock, 5);
   if(rc < 0){
      printf("listen failed");
      exit(1);
   }
   printf("hey");
   csocka = accept(csock, (struct sockaddr *) &caddr2, &clen);
   if(csocka < 0){
      printf("accept failed");
      exit(1);
   }

   while(1){
      read(csocka,&cbuf,sizeof(cbuf));
      time(&logtime);                                   //time of req.
      if(cbuf==NULL){
         cerror("400 Bad Request: empty request");
         write(csocka, &errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
         continue;
      }
      ttl = strlen(cbuf);
      while(cbuf[ttl-1] == '\n' || cbuf[ttl-1] == '\r'){
         cbuf[ttl--] = '\0';
      }
      if(sscanf(cbuf,"%[^ ] %[^ ] %[^ ]", method, uri, prot) != 3){
         cerror("400 Bad Request: Unexpected number of arguments");
         write(csocka, &errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
         continue;
      }
      if(method!="GET" || method !="HEAD"){
         cerror("405 Method Not Allowed: GET/HEAD only");
         write(csocka, &errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
         continue;
      }
      if(uri == (char*) 0){
         cerror("400 Bad Request: empty url");
         write(csocka, &errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
         continue;
      }
      printf("%s \n", cbuf);
   }

   close(csocka);

}
```

Comment: Are you certain you're running the same binary you compiled, and not a different build, or something else in your path with the same name?

Comment: yea im sure ive compiled multiple times

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'd be interested to know where the `direct://` URL scheme comes from and what it means.  It is not a defined scheme according to the IANA: <http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html>

Comment: The code doesn't appear to have any possibility of continuing after `argc!=3` so I must ask, have you tried `which myprogname` to ensure that you are executing the program you _think_ you are executing?  For example, if you've forgotten to run your program as `./myprogname` (or to add `.` to the beginning of your `PATH`) you could be running something else.  Related:  You aren't running your program from within a script, are you?  If so then perhaps the output is from the script instead.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason is that you aren't running your program, but some system program.

If you are on a Linux machine, type:

`which <program name>`

to find out which executable you are actually running.

type:

`./<program name>`

to run your program instead (provided that you are in the same directory as your executable).

Comment: thank you this solved it...how is it possible that i ran some program from a completely different directory...

Comment: when you type a program name (without an absolute or relative path), the shell searches your `$PATH` environment variable for matches. That's why I asked whether you were certain you were running the file you expected ...

Comment: I think most of us has made this beginner mistake. I named my first c program `test` and I was very confused before I realised that I was running `/usr/bin/test` and not `./test`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you ignoring the return value of `read`? What makes you think `read` is null-terminating `cbuf` for you? If `read` isn't null terminating `cbuf`, then what makes you think it's safe to pass buf to `strlen`? You're invoking undefined behaviour by passing something that isn't a string to strlen... The behaviour that follows may seem strange or inconsistent, but that's the nature of undefined behaviour.

```
int len = read(csocka,&cbuf,sizeof(cbuf));
if (len <= 0) {
    /* something went wrong in read().
     * report an error and stop here... */
    break;
}
/* Once error checking is performed, len is the number of bytes recieved by read. */
```

Consider the code above. Do you need the line `ttl=strlen(cbuf);`, if you correctly check for errors?

`printf("%s \n", cbuf);` is wrong, because cbuf isn't a string. Consider `fwrite(cbuf, len, stdout); putchar('\n');` or `printf("%.*s\n", len, stdout);`.

`write(csocka, &errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));` also looks wrong, but I'll leave that in your hands. If you need us to fix these kinds of errors for you, then your method of learning isn't working very well. Which book are you reading?